# Dynamically modify DNS to add a subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, php, subdomain

Is there a way to modify a domains DNS using PHP for example. I am not quite sure how a company can be in charge of a domains DNS (*Can I be?*)

What processes do GoDaddy (for example) go through when a user modifies a domains DNS record on their website?

I am wondering this because I am looking to make a Cpanel type thing for users on my server where a user can modify many things including adding a subdomain which is only possible by adding an A host or CNAME to the DNS.

Comment: [Bind](https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind) is a standard DNS Server that runs on Linux. As usual on Linux, configurations are stored in plain text files, and PHP is fully able to write text files...Also, Microsoft DNS Server can be managed with Powershell cmdlets that PHP could easily run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- delegate a zone to your nameservers
- Choose DNS server
- Choose preferable way to deal with DNS

Common ways to solve this problem:

- use DB as a backend and interact with it directly.

Two popular DNS servers are BIND and PowerDNS. Both can use MySQL as a backend but Bind (with built-in DLZ) has more restrictions if I recall correctly.

- generate zone files for Bind or NSD. You can use some template engine in php to generate zone files and then reload webserver
- DDNS (rfc 2136/2137)

RFC:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2136
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2137

Comment: bind configuration example:

http://www.kirya.net/articles/running-a-secure-ddns-service-with-bind/

PHP sdk:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-dns.net-dns-updates-example.php


This should be a good start for you.